# Create and test a simple list in Typescript over console

Tags: typescript

i shall create simple methods that create, and get an number from a list in Typescript. I don't have any idea how to make this. 
Can somebody help me to get the first method add? 
Here ist the code that we got:

```
class ListElement {
    public next: ListElement;
    public value: number;
}

abstract class List {
    protected first: ListElement;
    protected current: ListElement;

    public abstract add(value: number): void;

    public abstract remove(index: number): void;

    public abstract get(index: number): number;

    public abstract hasNext(): boolean;

    public abstract next(): number;

    public abstract clear(): void;
}

//here your code:

var array = new Array();

class MyList extends List{

    public add(): void{

    }
    public remove(): void{

    }
    public  get(): any{

    }
    public hasNext(): any{

    }
    public next(): any{

    }
    public clear(): void{


    }
}

//until here

let testListe: List = new MyList();
testListe.add(4);
testListe.add(2);
testListe.add(7);
testListe.add(100);
testListe.add(10);

testListe.remove(3);
testListe.remove(4);

console.log("Should be 10 : " + testListe.get(3));
console.log("Should be 4 : " + testListe.get(0));

console.log("Should be 2, 7, 10");
while(testListe.hasNext()) {
    console.log(testListe.next());
}

console.log("Should be undefined : " + testListe.next());

testListe.clear();
console.log("Should be undefined : " + testListe.get(0));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and the meta post [on asking homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). This said, the code you provided looks a bit too thin - at least try to implement the methods yourself. I'm unsure whether the code's supposed to use an array. The members `first` and `current` hint to a list implementation using linked elements.

Comment: this really sounds a lot like someone has to implement a linked listed as a homework for school. :)